# appendFormat of NSMutableString not append more one item

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I used `NSMutableString` and used `appendFormat` function, appendFormat set boundary and first image and not append any item more it, I don't know where the error.
result in debug:-

> 2016-03-08 15:52:56.385 PropertyTurkey[474:82387]
>   Body-----=-----011000010111000001101001
>
> Content-Disposition:form-data; name="image[]";
>   filename="/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A3EA5D3E-377E-4E16-9541-580BB57E211E/Documents/1.jpg"
>
> ÿØÿà

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001",
                                   @"cache-control": @"no-cache" };
        NSArray *parameters = @[ @{ @"name": @"image[]", @"fileName":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_chosenImagesPath[0]]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"image[]", @"fileName":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_chosenImagesPath[1]]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"image[]", @"fileName":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_chosenImagesPath[2]]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"image[]", @"fileName":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_chosenImagesPath[3]]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"image[]", @"fileName":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_chosenImagesPath[4]]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"rea_title", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_realEstateTitle] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"why_buy_property", @"value": @"why_buy_property" },
                                 @{ @"name": @"cit_id", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_cit_id]  },
                                 @{ @"name": @"are_id", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_are_id] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"garden_exterior", @"value":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_desOfGardenAndExter] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"home_interior", @"value":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_desOfHomeInterior] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"property_desc", @"value":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The property desc field is required."] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"typ_id", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_typ_id] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"rea_bedrooms", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_bedrooms] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"rea_bathrooms", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_bathrooms]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"rea_living_space", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_livingSpaceSqm] },
                                 @{ @"name": @"sta_id", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_sta_id]},
                                 @{ @"name": @"rea_price", @"value": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_price]} ];

        NSString *boundary = @"---011000010111000001101001";

        NSError *error;
        NSMutableString *body = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
        [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
            if (param[@"fileName"]) {
                [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]];
                //[body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", headers[@"content-type"]];
                NSLog(@"%@",headers[@"content-type"]);
                [body appendFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:param[@"fileName"] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding error:&error]];
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", error);
                }
            } else {
                [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]];
                [body appendFormat:@"%@", param[@"value"]];
            }
            NSLog(@"Body-----=%@",body);
        }
        [body stringByAppendingFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
        NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.123/api/v1/sellProperty?api_key=%@&auth_token=%@&device_token=%@",apiKey,check,deviceToken]]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                           timeoutInterval:10.0];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
         NSLog(@"%@",headers);

        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                        if (error) {
                                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                        } else {
                                                             NSDictionary *serializedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                                                            NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                                                            NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                             NSLog(@"res %@ serializedData %@", response,serializedData);

                                                        }
                                                    }];
        [dataTask resume];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I replace this line

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"content-type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"multipart/form-data"];
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"cache-control" forHTTPHeaderField:@"no-cache"];
        [manager POST:@"http://182.1698.133.45873/sellProperty?" parameters:par constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            int x=0;
            for (UIImage *imag in _chosenImages)
            {
                //[formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image[]"];
                NSLog(@"%@",imag);
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imag, 0.5);
                NSLog(@"%@",imageData);
                [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image[]" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",x] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                x++;
            }

        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

its work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are using stringByAppendingFormat which creates a new string, not adding anything to an existing string.

Comment: thank you for your answer i used it after for loop, but when check it in fro loop it just have one value like the above result

Comment: Gnasher is right - replace stringByAppendingFormat with appendFormat, which you use everywhere else.  In addition, you might want to look at the AFNetworking third party library, which makes this process a bit easier. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: @Ahmed Within the for loop, the string builds up just fine.